# Multiple delegates/datasources in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Objective-c `delegates` entertain one `instance` at a time like if I have two `view controllers` and both implementing same delegate, but only currently presented `view controller` receive callbacks.

If I have a two `uitableviews` in same `view controller` both `uitableview's` `delagates`  `datasource` are set like

```
tb1.datasource = self; 
tb2.datasource = self;

tb1.delegate = self; 
tb2.delegate = self;
```

How uitableview's working with delegates defined at same time?

Comment: You need to make sure that both tb1 & tb2 instances exists in memory to recieve callbacks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your delegate/datasource methods will be called twice, once for every table, and you can detect which table was called from:

For example:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == tb1)
        return 10;
    else if (tableView == tb2)
        return 8;
}
```

That's the reason the caller tableView is passed as a variable in the methods, so you can detect where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Two `UITableViews` in a `UIViewController` means two instances of `tableViews` in a view controller. So if you are setting `dataSource` and `delegate` of two tableView instances, its means you both tableView call same `delegate` and `dataSource` methods. Now if you want different functionality for tableViews you can set tag on tableViews and in method check that tag and perform specific task depending on that tag.